# Apachebench request count and Node.js script counter don't match

Tags: node.js, apachebench

No doubt I'm doing something stupid, but I've been having problems running a simple node.js app using the Nerve micro-framework. Testing with apachebench, it seems that the code within my single controller is being invoked more frequently than the app itself is being called.

I've created a test script like so:

```
'use strict';

(function () {
    var path = require('path');
    var sys = require('sys');
    var nerve = require('/var/www/libraries/nerve/nerve');
    var nerveCounter = 0;

    r_server.on("error", function (err) {
        console.log("Error " + err);
    });

    var app = [
        ["/", function(req, res) {
            console.log("nc = " + ++nerveCounter);
       }]
    ];

    nerve.create(app).listen(80);
}());
```

Start the server. From another box, run a load test:

```
/usr/sbin/ab -n 5000 -c 50 http://<snip>.com/
...
Complete requests:      5000
...
Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
...
 100%    268 (longest request)
```

But the node script itself is printing all the way up to:

```
nc = 5003
rc = 5003
```

In other words, the server is being called 5000 times but the controller code is being called 5003 times.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**Updated**

I changed the tone and content of this question significantly to reflect the help Colum, Alfred and GregInYEG gave me in realising that the problem did not lie with Redis or Nerve and probably lie with apachebench.

Comment: Can you add some code that increments a file, because it might be something weird that is going on with your script. Not Redis.

Comment: Thanks for the idea Colum - I added a couple of global counters (see above). The counters ran to 5003 as well - proving that the problem was not with Redis.

Comment: p.s: I think you should remove the node_redis code altogether because even that you updated your title it could still look like the node_redis code is to blame.

Comment: It looks like Apache Bench can send more requests than you've requested. "The ‘ab’ tool does in fact measure the completion of its requests properly, but it may actually send more requests than you ask it to. That’s because it counts replies not requests." See this blog post for more info: http://adrianotto.com/2010/05/apache-benchmark-ab-is-not-exact/

Comment: Thanks GregIn - confirmed that this seems to be the issue. I re-ran the test with Express instead of Nerve and the problem recurred.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. As I commented below Alfred's answer, I'd still recommend Express at the moment, as it is being actively maintained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Program:

```
const PORT = 3000;
const HOST = 'localhost';
const express = require('express');
const app = module.exports = express.createServer();
const redis = require('redis');
const client = redis.createClient();

app.get('/incr', function(req, res) {
    client.incr('counter', function(err, reply) {
        res.send('incremented counter to:' + reply.toString() + '\n');
    });
});

app.get('/reset', function(req, res) {
    client.del('counter', function(err, reply) {
        res.send('resetted counter\n');
    });
});

app.get('/count', function(req, res) {
    client.get('counter', function(err, reply) {
        res.send('counter: ' + reply.toString() + '\n');
    });
});

if (!module.parent) {
    app.listen(PORT, HOST);
    console.log("Express server listening on port %d", app.address().port);
}
```

### Conclusion

It works without any flaws on my computer:

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 10.10 \n \l

$ uname -a
Linux alfred-laptop 2.6.35-24-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 2 01:41:57 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux

$ node -v
v0.2.6

$ npm install express hiredis redis
npm info build Success: redis@0.5.2
npm info build Success: express@1.0.3
npm info build Success: hiredis@0.1.6

$  ./redis-server --version
Redis server version 2.1.11 (00000000:0)

$ git clone -q git@gist.github.com:02a3f7e79220ea69c9e1.git gist-02a3f7e7; cd gist-02a3f7e7; node index.js

$ #from another tab

$ clear; curl http://localhost:3000/reset; ab -n 5000 -c 50 -q http://127.0.0.1:3000/incr > /dev/null; curl http://localhost:3000/count;

resetted counter
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking 127.0.0.1 (be patient)
Completed 500 requests
Completed 1000 requests
Completed 1500 requests
Completed 2000 requests
Completed 2500 requests
Completed 3000 requests
Completed 3500 requests
Completed 4000 requests
Completed 4500 requests
Completed 5000 requests
Finished 5000 requests


Server Software:        
Server Hostname:        127.0.0.1
Server Port:            3000

Document Path:          /incr
Document Length:        25 bytes

Concurrency Level:      50
Time taken for tests:   1.172 seconds
Complete requests:      5000
Failed requests:        4991
   (Connect: 0, Receive: 0, Length: 4991, Exceptions: 0)
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      743893 bytes
HTML transferred:       138893 bytes
Requests per second:    4264.61 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       11.724 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.234 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          619.61 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.5      0       7
Processing:     4   11   3.3     11      30
Waiting:        4   11   3.3     11      30
Total:          5   12   3.2     11      30

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     11
  66%     13
  75%     14
  80%     14
  90%     15
  95%     17
  98%     19
  99%     24
 100%     30 (longest request)
counter: 5000
```

Comment: Many thanks Alfred for taking the time to check this out. The problem is definitely not with Redis - the global counters I added show that somehow the "/" code is being called more than 5000 times. When I swapped out the Nerve code and added in your Express code, then the app started behaving itself - so the problem is definitely either somehow with my app, or with the Nerve library itself. I'm going to update the title of my question so it's more obvious where the problem lies - perhaps the Nerve author will take a look at it and tell me what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Very gppd! I think you should use express anyway. It is the most popular maintained node.js development framework! Why are you using Nerve? Latest commit was 11 June. P.S: Nerve isn't even in npm!

Comment: Was using it because I read some blog posts saying nice things about Nerve, but you're right - it's clearly not being kept up-to-date. Moving to Express now. I've left an issue in the Nerve GitHub project pointing to this question in case gritter wants to reply/fix the problem.

Comment: Okay very good :). Express.js is a very good library :P. P.S: thanks for the approval :)

Comment: I'm gjritter from github. As Alfred noted, you're probably better off using express. It's well maintained and updated, whereas I have not been updating nerve for quite some time. I will try to investigate this problem when I have a chance.

Comment: Alfred I've rerun the test with Express and encountered the same problem - node.js count > ab count. I suspect your test passed because you were running within localhost. I think if you had done it across network, then requests > responses and you would have had slight differences in the counts as I did.

Comment: When you use a single box you don't need to connect over network to redis. You could even use unix domain socket to speed it up more. It could also be ab. You should try siege which is a better tool to do benchmarking. P.S: what version of redis are you using?

Comment: Redis 2.0.4 - I'm pretty sure the problem lies with ab but am moving to Express anyway. Better safe than sorry

Comment: hehe I also am pretty sure that is the case :P. How about if you perform benchmark/test with [siege](http://www.joedog.org/index/siege-home). On the most Linux distro's you can find it in repo.